# Last.fm web API doesn't paginate search results

Tags: python, api, last.fm

I'm trying to get all instances of a certain song using the last.fm web api, but I seem to be getting the exact same results, regardless of the page number.

This is the URL I'm using:
`requests.get("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track=" + song + "&api_key=" + API_KEY + "&startPage=" + str(page_number) + "&format=json")`

Is there something I'm missing, or is the pagination on the search portion of the api just...broken?

Comment: If you pull out the URL into a separate variable, can you verify that it looks like you expect? Specifically, the `str(page_number)` part

Comment: Yep. Everything looks like it should look. `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track=jingle+bells&api_key=myapikey&startPage=0&format=json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t find official documentation for their pagination, but based on [last.fm API pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846040/last-fm-api-pagination), it looks like you might want `page=` instead of `startPage=`.

Comment: You're right! That actually worked. I do get some weird repeats of pages, but at least pages are changing now. Thanks!